# WMQ replicate message to another queue

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I have 2 queues say Q1 and Q2. When I insert messages using MQPUT into Q1, is there any way that this message be replicated into Q2?
Does WMQ have support for queue copy?
Note : The queues reside on different queue managers.

Thanks,
Hudson

Comment: let me refine my requirement based on nitgeek's suggestion. An application reads data from a queue say Q1 (in my case an alias queue) on queue manager QMA. Now the queue Q2 on queue manager QMB gets the data by subscribing to a topic on QMA to which Q1 posts. The problem here is that the application reads data from Q1 which is an alias queue and doesnt get the data. How can this be modelled so that the application as well as Q2 gets the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have multiple consumers(Queues), which needs the same message, then **Publish-Subscribe** is made exactly for this purpose.

You can refer [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.amqnar.doc/ps10120_.htm) for details about pub-sub.

If you are using Websphere MQ 7.XX, then you can use an **Alias queue to publish** the message.

You can follow below steps:

> 1. Create a new Topic(Lets say "MyTopic" is your topic).
> 2. Create an Alias queue(Lets call it as "MyPublisher"), with Base Type as **Topic** and give Base Object as "MyTopic"(Name of your topic).
> 3. Now say Q1, Q2, Q3 have to get the message. Create subscriptions for these queues for Topic "MyTopic".

Now, the messages posted in queue "MyPublisher", will reach to all queues subscribing to the topic "MyTopic"(Q1,Q2,Q3).

Even remote queues can be given in destination while creating subscriptions. So, different queue managers will not be a problem as far as you have connectivity between them.

Comment: Is it possible to subscribe to a remote topic? Given that Queues Q2 and Q3 reside on a one queue manager and the topic is on another queue manager

Comment: No. As such message published in 1 queue manager will not be visible to another queue manager. Although, If the two queue managers are in the same cluster and the topic is also clustered, then it is possible.

Comment: But as I said in my reply, a remote queue can subscribe to the topic. So, you can create a remote queue via which message can go to your remote queue manager's local queue.

Comment: do we need to set up a channel for remote queue? can you guide me in achieving this with a remote queue?

Comment: Yes, you need a sender channel on the sending side and a receiver channel on the receiving side(with the same name as the sender channel). Look at this link http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.explorer.tutorials.doc%2Fbi00203_.htm

Comment: Thanks :) .. I am able to get the message on a remote queue

Comment: The alias queue is the only queue on qmgr1, so when the message arrived on this alias queue gets posted on a topic, will it be available if i do a MQGET on this alias queue?

Comment: No, it will not be available. But, it will surely reach the active subscribers.

Comment: Nice answer! There is an official [IBM Support](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21574670) page for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bother with all of the Pub/Sub stuff, then have a look at the free open source project Message Multiplexer (MMX) at http://www.capitalware.biz/mmx_overview.html

Its purpose is to read messages from a source queue and put the exact same message to 'n' target queues (up to 99).

The download contains builds for AIX, HP-UX, Linux, IBM i (OS/400), Solaris, Windows and z/OS (mainframe).

MMX is a very simple and straight-forward program to use.

Comment: I don't think we should implement multi-phase commit outside of MQ

Comment: @siddhusingh weird that you would post a comment like that without first looking the MMX's documentation or the source code.  It does NOT perform a "multi-phase commit".   MMX uses MQ's MQCMIT and MQBACK API calls to perform single phase UOW (Unit of Work).